# FriendsPickerFragment - how to show friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've managed to login and display the friendsPickerFragment which I've added to my sample app in order to show my friends.

When this fragment opens then I get an empty list but no errors or such. I realize that only users who have that same app installed and are my friends on FB will be shown on this list, right? So here's what I did:

- I've installed my app on Device 1 which is logged into my fb account - lets call it "Account1".
- I've installed same app on Device 2 which is logged into another fb account - "Account2" which is also MY FRIEND on fb.

After doing those two, I still dont see any of them being shown in friendsPicker thing. Are there any other steps to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - everything was set up the right way except I had to create fb test users in the app page. Once I've added some test users, I was able to see them in the app.